# Automatic scale block depending on viewport scale?

Tags: autocad

In autocad i am trying to make a block that will automaticly scale, depending on the viewport scale where it is visible in. 
So far, without luck. Also through google i cant seem to find anything related.
So i was wondering, is this even possible to make ?

Comment: Have you looked at Annotative Scaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Miirr says, you can use an annotative block for this. An annotative block can have multiple scales, rotations and multiple positions. Please read the documentation here : http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%202010%20User%20Documentation/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ff1bb1a0510dab2fb04a-7f5c.htm,topicNumber=d0e111300